# How do I calculate the start/end of an interval (set of rows) containing identical values?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Assume we have a spark DataFrame that looks like the following (ordered by `time`):

```python
+------+-------+
| time | value |
+------+-------+
|    1 | A     |
|    2 | A     |
|    3 | A     |
|    4 | B     |
|    5 | B     |
|    6 | A     |
+------+-------+
```

I'd like to calculate the start/end times of each sequence of uninterrupted values. The expected output from the above DataFrame would be:

```python
+-------+-------+-----+
| value | start | end |
+-------+-------+-----+
| A     |     1 |   3 |
| B     |     4 |   5 |
| A     |     6 |   6 |
+-------+-------+-----+
```

(The `end` value for the final row could also be `null`.)

Doing this with a simple group aggregation:

```python
.groupBy("value")
.agg(
    F.min("time").alias("start"),
    F.max("time").alias("end")
)
```

doesn't take into account the fact that the same `value` can appear in multiple different intervals.

Answer (score 1):

the idea is to create an identifier for each group and use it to group by and compute your min and max time.

assuming `df` is your dataframe:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df = df.withColumn(
    "fg", 
    F.when(
        F.lag('value').over(Window.orderBy("time"))==F.col("value"), 
        0
    ).otherwise(1)
)

df = df.withColumn(
    "rn",     
    F.sum("fg").over(
        Window
        .orderBy("time")
        .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
    )
)
```

From that point, you have your dataframe with an identifier for each consecutive group.

```py
df.show()

+----+-----+---+---+                                                            
|time|value| rn| fg|
+----+-----+---+---+
|   1|    A|  1|  1|
|   2|    A|  1|  0|
|   3|    A|  1|  0|
|   4|    B|  2|  1|
|   5|    B|  2|  0|
|   6|    A|  3|  1|
+----+-----+---+---+
```

then you just have to do the aggregation

```py
df.groupBy(
    'value', 
    "rn"
).agg(
    F.min('time').alias("start"),
    F.max('time').alias("end")
).drop("rn").show()
+-----+-----+---+                                                               
|value|start|end|
+-----+-----+---+
|    A|    1|  3|
|    B|    4|  5|
|    A|    6|  6|
+-----+-----+---+
```